# How can I censor entries at failure or an exit age in Stata?

Tags: survival, stata

I am attempting to construct a survival analysis in Stata whereby subjects fail if the failure condition is met (Staph) but are also removed from the model once they are over 1100 days old.  My current script is -

`stset new_end_age, id(CPID) failure(Staph==1) exit(time new_end_age>=1100) origin(time birth_dt) scale(1)`

Which results in the following output -

```
id:  CPID

failure event:  Staph == 1

obs. time interval:  (new_end_age[_n-1], new_end_age]

exit on or before:  time new_end_age>=1100

t for analysis:  (time-origin)

origin:  time birth_dt


54592  total obs.
 1898  ignored because never entered
36124  obs. end on or before enter()
16387  obs. begin on or after exit

  183  obs. remaining, representing
  183  subjects
    0  failures in single failure-per-subject data
  421168  total analysis time at risk, at risk from t =         0
                         earliest observed entry t =         0
                              last observed exit t =     11892
```

However this is incorrect as I know that there are multiple entries for individual subjects that should remain, and some of these should fail in my time period of interest.
I need a command that prioritises the failure condition and if this is not met subjects are removed at `t=1100`.

Comment: May be you need to specify `enter()` option as well, as Stata has excluded 2/3 of your data right away (and ignored a few more). Is that what you intended? Also, judging by the syntax diagram, you can specify an `exp` in the `exit()` option, so something like `exit( time new_end_age >= 11000 | Staph == 1)` can be tried. (I have never worked with `st` data in Stata, I have to admit.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now worked out that the way I had constructed the `st` function meant that subjects were failing when they should have been censored.  By stipulating the true failure event within the exit function, the censoring worked correctly - `exit(Staph==1 time 1500)`